# Does every update still wipe progress in Spintires?

Tags: spintires

[Source](https://steamcommunity.com/id/maluno1/recommended/263280/) (a Steam review posted on 29 Oct, 2015):

> ...one day they [the developer] released an update and I found out my
>   20-something hours worth of advances had been wiped out.
>
> Looking around in the forums, it soon became apparent that it wasn't
>   just me nor was this the first time it happened. In fact it happened
>   with every single update done before.
>
> I forgot about it for some time, and came back a while
>   later. Soon enough came another update, and down the drain those extra few hours did go.
>
> In the wake of complaints in the forums, I remember reading an
>   announcement by Oovee stating they would be having a meeting with the
>   developer and would 'explain to him how important
>   maintaining the saved game progress across updates seemed to be to the
>   players'.
>
> Today, about half a year later, came another update and,
>   unsurprisingly, another wipe.

Comment: You should probably update the question body to ask the question you want it to ask...

Comment: @Vemonus: Is repeating necessary?

Comment: not usually, but since your question body is just a big quote, id say in this case, yeah, it'd be helpful